# converting from long to double with decimal point

Tags: java, long-integer

I have some numbers as long type I want to convert it to double with specific decimal point figures.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long l = 14253638;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.0000");
        System.out.println(df.format(l));
    }
}
```

expected printed value : 14.2536

but actual printed value : 14253638.0000

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Can you show us all of the (relevant) code you have made?

Comment: @Choirbean look at it now. I edited it.

Comment: Doubles do not have specific (minimum number of points). You might be better of with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

We can do it via a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
long l = 1443156430;
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(l).movePointLeft(4);
```

Results in:

> `144315.6430`

To get it to a `double`:

```
double result = bd.doubleValue();
```

Note however that a `BigDecimal` may not be able to be represented precisely using a `double`.

---

EDIT: It's not very clear what precisely your requirements are - *if it's a 2 digit number followed by 4 digits after the decimal point*, then you can manipulate a string length:

```
String truncated = String.valueOf(l).substring(0, 6);
double result = new BigDecimal(truncated).movePointLeft(4).doubleValue();
```

This produces:

> `14.4315`

Comment: this prints the decimal point after for digits from the left. but I want it to be printed after two digits from the right and have only 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @Moe:  This answer's pretty close; it'll get you to where you need to go from here.

Comment: @Makoto I have no idea on how to reformat it to the desired format.

Comment: @Moe:  Think about it.  The long has had its decimal moved over four places to the left with that code.